# Xcode plugin for Jenkins // Copy Pods Resources failed

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I'm trying to set up CI for my iOS project using Jenkins and Xcode plugin. This project uses [cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/).

When I try to build the project I see the following message in the console output.

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution "Copy Pods Resources" "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-aigdarcpcvxsuigtchghvivjocka/Build/Intermediates/MyProjectName.build/Ad Hoc-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Script-995B1F2BEF504DDDA6A68507.sh"
```

I've checked Jenkins user's permissions to write to these folders - they are OK.

What could be a cause? Any thoughts are very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Do you check in your Pods folder? Do you run `pod install` before building your project?

Comment: @MishieMoo Xcode 4.6. "Do you check in your Pods folder? Do you run pod install before building your project?" - do you mean that Jenkins has to run pod install before building the project? is it ok if I run it before manually?

Comment: If you are not checking in your Pods folder, you need to run `pod install` before each build. This should be done as a build step in Jenkins, as the entire point is to automate the entire build process.

Comment: Are you using any local repository pods? If yes you have to make this repository available on your CI-Server as well…

Answer (score -1):

Try Running 'pod install' before the xcode part of the build